# How to remove or change an image in a docx

Tags: opentbs, tinybutstrong

I'm trying to change an image embedded in a docx.  In some circumstances I'll need to replace a default placeholder image on each page with a new one, and in others I'd like to just remove that placeholder image (or hide it? -- or better than hide it, just leave it alone because the placeholder image right now is just a simple almost invisible 1x1 image).  First choice I suppose would be to entirely remove it though.

What are the best ways to do this in TBS?  I figure I could *always* replace the image whether I really have one to display there or want it removed, and just replace it with a tiny 1x1 white pixel PNG or something.  But is there a cleaner way to do this that's no more difficult than that approach?

I'm trying to use this method right now:

```
$TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_CHANGE_PICTURE, $imageId, "$writeTemp$tmpDirNm\\QR1__$imageId.png");
```

But thought I'd check in since I didn't yet determine a better way to do this.

Thanks,

John

Comment: One quick follow up too, could you update the OpenTBS version number here https://www.tinybutstrong.com/plugins.php ? It still says 1.7.6 which threw me for a loop for awhile causing me to think I had the latest version installed.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no direct way to delete a picture with OpenTBS.
But you can do it using a magnet field.

Example at the template side :

```
[my_pic_ok;ope=mok:1;magnet=w:r] 
[onshow.my_pic;ope=changepic;tagpos=inside]
```

PHP side:

```
$my_pic_ok = 0; // 0 = delete the picture, 1 = keep the picture
$TBS->MergeField('my_pic_ok', $my_pic_ok);
```